# Xcode can't create output file, permission denied

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction, permissions

In Xcode I cannot compile my application anymore, the error is:

```
/usr/bin/lipo: can't create output file: /Users/nathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PackageTracking-fpewhfohxohurlexwettvkopakyn/Build/Products/Release/PackageTracking.app/Contents/MacOS/PackageTracking (Permission denied)
error: couldn't remove '/Users/nathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PackageTracking-fpewhfohxohurlexwettvkopakyn/Build/Products/Release/PackageTracking.app/Contents/MacOS/PackageTracking' after command failed: Permission denied
```

This folder was created by Xcode, why do I get a permission denied?

I tried to do a clean, same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you logged on to the `nathan` user account?

Have you tried deleting tho derived date location in Organiser and trying again?
[image]

Comment: worked, deleted all the data. It doesn't explain the error, but it works for now.

Comment: Could be lots of things - a flipped permission bit, a tiny bit of hard drive corruption…

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue with permission denied to create folders in the `/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode` folder.

What fixed things for me was to do the following in terminal

```
sudo chown -R username /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode
```

Comment: thank you @Brian Broom. The above command make me to access the permission denied files successfully. :-