# Xcode Build Issue - permission denied

Tags: xcode, permissions

I am using Xcode 10.1. Everytime I build my project I get this error:

> /Users/{username}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{random_name}/Build/Intermediates.noindex/....
> line 2: /Users/{username}/path_to_app/Pods/Target Support
> Files/pod_name/... Permission denied

I already tried the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402003/xcode-cant-create-output-file-permission-denied). I also tried doing the `sudo chown` but those did not fix the error. These are the actual steps I did, multiple times:

1. Remove all files in the DerivedData
2. Do the sudo chown in both paths: DerivedData and path_to_app
3. Clean
4. Build

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you do `chown` with `-R` / `--recursive`?

Comment: Hi @shim I just did but I got a "Operation not permitted" for each and every file in my app's directory.

Comment: Doubt it will help but have you tried Disk Utility's "First Aid" ?

Comment: Plus [this](http://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/) might help

Comment: Seems like that is only available for Mojave. I only have High Sierra.

Comment: try this https://testersupport.usertesting.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003712912-How-to-Trust-an-Unreleased-iOS-App

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What worked for me is using `chmod`. Here's the command `chmod -R 755 {my_working_folder}`. For an explanation of what the numbers represent, you may read [this article](http://www.macinstruct.com/node/415).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me.Navigate to the directory which contains the file (for which you receive "Permission Denied" error) ,Then in terminal type chmod 777 (your_file_name). What basically you are doing is giving read/write/execute permission to your file . For more info check this article - https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/